Remove content with Turbo without a dedicated action
Is there a quick way to remove the content of a div (replace with "") with Turbo?
I have a popup, and when clicking on X, I want to remove it.
I understand I can add an action and replace the content within the turbo stream format. But I'd rather avoid to add a route just for that.

Just do plain JS. Create a Stimulus controller and attach a click action on a button to remove the content of the Stimulus target you want.

Thanks. That is what I ended up doing.  close() {     this.element.replaceChildren()   }

This is not Turbo's prerogative. Turbo is essentially a protocol for you to be able to control the browser's content from your backend (e.g. by sending back messages to remove/replace particular elements).
If you would rather not make a trip to the server (which makes sense in some cases) there's another part of the HOTWIRE suite for that:  Stimulus.
Make a controller you can attach to that turbo frame, and implement the behavior.
Here's an interesting article that should introduce you to the concepts: Self-destructing StimulusJS controllers
